# Bower register - EPERM, unlink with tar.gz

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, bower, bower-register

i'm running this command to register my custom angular package to my git repository:

```
bower register EditProprietorPackege https://github.com/myuser/directiveTest.git
```

Bower return me this error: [Error on PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/V2cG85c5)

As suggested in other Stackoverflow questions about this error, i uninstalled/reinstalled Bower, updated uncompress-zip, updated the permission to NodeJs folder but the error is still here.

Am i missing something?

Comment: try running the cmd as administrator.

Comment: @ɦassansin already tryied, also with powershell but it doesn't work